# How do I know in client if MongoDB cluster has primary?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

It is possible to connect to a MongoDB cluster which currently does not have by setting "connectWithNoPrimary" to "true". Then, however, it will still be possible to read but not write. I need a way to know if that's the case in an Express middleware. Sadly did not find a way to do that.
I know there is "mongoose.connection.readyState" which tells me if the connection is ready is there something similar to know if I can write?

Thanks!

Comment: Well you sort of can, but it's kind of involved since it means getting into the interal states of things. I think the real thing to ask here is *"Why do you think you want this?"*. The reason I ask is because unless you are actually writing some management tool to monitor the current replica set state, then your otherwise "normal" application should not care. It simply should be allowed to read, and error on writes until a primary is elected. You might say *"I need to know"*, but I contest that you actually really should not need to know at all. Let the driver handle it.

Comment: First thanks for the answer. Without going into too much not needed detail the reason I need it is to check in a middleware if writing is possible or not. Depending on that can I then simply return before it hits other middleware (like session storage) or routes which can not handle it and error.

Comment: What I'm actually saying here is *"check in a middleware if writing is possible or not"* is **not** actually a responsibility of your application code. Or at the very least it **should not** be. By default, the driver is just going to "queue" operatons until a primary becomes available. 9/10 times, that should be pretty soon. If you really must you can reduce or turn off the queuing and get write errors immediately. My real point is that in the context of what you are asking, this really is not for you. At most you want immediate error, but I'd probably still advise against that.

Comment: Yes thanks, I totally understand what you are saying and I am aware of it. But the problem is more complex and going into depth and explaining my reasons would make it for sure clear but would still result in the same question I asked above (but would simply be to much for here). There are always very good general rules which seem to apply always but even they have many exceptions.

Comment: Like for example "Do not jump of high buildings" with an almost unlimited amount of exceptions like: unless its burning and your chance is survival is higher, you are very sick and in your country there is no "assisted dying", ... and even more ;-). So assuming I have a good reason to do that is there a way to achive it?